# How to disguise a button to look like a checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've a got checkbox that when clicked needs to submit a form, even without the help of javascript. Thus, I am creating a form with a single button inside and attempting to disguise that button as a checkbox.

So far I have this as my HTML:

```
<form>
    <button class="checkbox" type="submit">
    </button>
</form>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    padding: 0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

What am I missing to make this class compatible with IE, Safari, Opera, etc?

Also, how can I make the button appear checked?

Comment: _even without the help of javascript_ but you need JavaScript to submit a form using just a checkbox.

Comment: @Mikey I'm not using an actual checkbox. I'm using a button and disguising that button as a checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to the answer before about adding [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) you can make it appear checked by adding the checkmark in the `html`

```css
.checkbox {
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
   -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
   -moz-appearance: checkbox;
   -ms-appearance: checkbox; 
   -o-appearance: checkbox;
   appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
    <button class="checkbox" type="submit">✔</button>
```

apparently Firefox won't show any content inside the button, so i suggest not to use `appearance` but just put the tick inside the button and it will look like a checkbox, not the default checkbox in Firefox but if you can't tolerate that you'll have to use an overlay or `svg` to get around it

```css
.checkbox {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;       
}
```

```html
 <button class="checkbox" type="submit">✔</button>
```

Comment: It looks like the checkmark doesn't appear in Firefox

Comment: yeah Firefox won't let you put any content in the button using `-moz-appearance` , i updated my answer for an alternative

Answer (score 2):

`-ms-appearance` for IE and
`-o-appearance` for Opera

This is called vendor prefix by the way.

Comment: Thanks guys! How about making the button appear checked? Is that possible?

Comment: And what for other browsers? Firefox, Chroom, Safari?

Answer (score 0):

you can use svg:

```css
.button{
  display: inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:30px;
  padding:20px 30px;
  border:3px solid orangered;
  background:white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position:relative;
  cursor:pointer;}
 
.icon {
  display: inline-block; 
  stroke-width: 0;
  width:30px;
  fill: orangered;
  position:absolute;
  line-height:0;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
 
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="">
  <button class="button">
  <svg class="icon icon-checkmark" viewbox="0 0 32 32">
    <path d="M27 4l-15 15-7-7-5 5 12 12 20-20z"></path>
  </svg>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: a `span` won't submit the form

Comment: he can do with js

Comment: the first line of the question is : `I've a got checkbox that when clicked needs to submit a form, even without the help of javascript. `

Comment: Yes, @Taki is correct. I need this to work without javascript